# Тип LPVOID и как им пользоваться (С++)

Tags: winapi, c++

Здравствуйте.

Недавно начал работу с каналами передачи данных, ну те которые NamedPipe.

Функции записи и чтения в канал, если рассматривать самую основу выглядят так:

```
WriteFile(HANDLE hFile, LPVOID lpBuffer, ... );
ReadFile(HANDLE hFile, LPVOID lpBuffer, ... );
```

С первым параметром все ясно, это канал в который пишем, но вот второй. Второй параметр типа `LPVOID` судя из описания в [Типы данных Windows](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Refer_API/type_date_windows.htm) есть указатель на любой тип.

Однако в канал кроме `char` ничего записать нельзя (так же и со чтением), компилятор говорит, что не может конвертировать, скажем `int` в `LPVOID`.

Вопрос, как работать с `LPVOID`? Может надо инт в него перевести или как то по другому?
И почему тогда компилятор на `char` не ругается?(Только если этот `cahr` объявлен так: `char *X = new char[const];` )

Еще вопрос: Писать в поток можно любой тип. Как читать из потока в переменную любого типа? Ничего не получается, только в `char` можно, который объявлен через `new char`
(компилятор пропускает, но при чтении происходит ошибка 998 `Invalid access to memory location`.)

Comment: Ну компилятору можно и по ушам надавать, если надо. Но. Там должен быть адрес. Соответсвенно преобразовывать в LPVOID надо не int, а int*.

Comment: Спасибо) Попробую)

Comment: @BlackOverlord спасибо за ссылку очень полезно.

Comment: > Еще вопрос: Писать в поток можно любой тип. Как читать из потока в переменную любого типа? Ничего не получается, только в char можно, который объявлен через new char (компилятор пропускает, но при чтении происходит ошибка 998 Invalid access to memory location.)

конкретный пример плз

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще, ясно, что LPVOID - это указатель. При этом это указатель (P от **P**ointer) на что угодно (VOID), да еще и дальний (L - от **L**ong). Т.е. это получается вот такая штука:

```
typedef void far *LPVOID;
```

Но, во-первых, я не уверен, что в Windows спецификатор far сейчас актуален, т.к. используется плоская модель памяти. В более ранних версиях компиляторов и ОС это наверняка имело значение. Вспоминаю мучения с Borland 3.1, в котором модель памяти играла очень большую роль. Во-вторых, неправильно приводить свои указатели к типу отличному от LPVOID при вызовах указанных системных ф-ций. Дело в том, что в следующих версиях ОС и инструментальных средств разработки могут переопределить этот тип и тогда кранты. Поэтому правильно сделать так:

```
int *blablabla; // наш указатель
LPVOID lpData;

lpData = (LPVOID)blablabla;
// или правильнее lpData = static_cast<LPVOID>(blablabla);
```

Ну, и далее уже передаем в ф-цию указатель lpData

Comment: Ну, сама-то переменная lpData вряд ли нужна. Достаточно

    WriteFile(...,(LPVOID)blablabla, ...)

Comment: Да уж. 

В vs есть

    typedef void *LPVOID;
    typedef void far            *LPVOID;

доступен тот что с far.

Хотя я был точно уверен, что это обычный void. 
Сам far это просто

    #define far

Comment: Соглашусь. Переменная не нужна. Но может пригодиться. Это во-первых. А, во-вторых, лучше все-таки с++-style cast.

Comment: @gecube, если переменная еще для чего-нибудь нужна, то конечно, ее надо делать.

--

Кстати, а чем именно *static_cast* лучше? Можете доходчиво объяснить?

Я, безусловно, не раз читал об этом, но видимо не проникаюсь **зачем в реальных программах** это (static_cast) нужно, поэтому постоянно забываю объяснения.

Comment: Ну, кроме того, что `static_cast` выглядит по-уродски и длиннее, у него есть преимущество. С style cast работает так, что сначала пытается сделать `static_cast`, затем `reinterpret_cast`. При необходимости он может сделать и `const_cast`. Т.е. получается, что запись-то лаконичнее, но преобразование небезопасно. И неопытные пользователи зачастую бездумно используют c-style cast, чтобы заткнуть предупреждения и ошибки компилятора.
Вот пример кода: http://ideone.com/Eu7a4l
И это мы еще не дошли до указателей на классы.

Comment: Ага, теперь вспомнил. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну да. Ещё, как пишут, скобки легче отслеживать, понятней, к какому значению применяется cast.

Ну и длина тоже полезна. Чем меньше cast'ов --тем лучше.

Comment: Ну, а черт его знает. const_cast понятнее, чем (bla_bla_bla_my_type*) из const-указателя. Да и поиск по исходникам по [static|const|reinterpret]_cast'ам проще, чем по скобкам... С этими скобками черт ногу сломит.

Comment: Ответы на такие вопросы надо вообще общими делать!

Answer (score 5):

Это вроде обычный void*?

```
// создаем переменную на которую будет ссылаться наш указатель
int var = 5;
std::cout << "\nvar=" << (int)var;

// создаем указатель на неопределенный тип
void * pointer;
pointer = &var; // помещаем в указатель адрес переменной var

// теперь приводим указатель к типу int и выполняем доступ по значеннию
std::cout << "\nуказатель=" << *(int*)pointer;
```

В результате мы должны получить вывод 5

```
// приводим указатель void * pointer к указателю int * 
int * pointer_int = (int*)pointer;

// осуществляем разыменование указателя int *.  То есть
// выполняем доступ по значению
int var2 = *pointer_int;
std::cout << "\nvar2=" << var2;

// Таким образом всё это выглядит так:
// pointer ->  (int*)pointer привели к требуемому ->  *(int*)pointer  разыменовали приведенный к типу указатель.
```

Comment: не совсем обычный void. См. мой ответ.