# Работа с потоками, передача данных между потоками

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, как правильно передавать параметр в функцию потока. То есть как передать "а" в метод Func? Я читал что вроде бы 4 параметр метода CreateThread и есть полем для параметра.

```
int main(){
DWORD dID;
HANDLE h;
int a;

h = CreateThread(NULL,0,Func,0,0,&dID);
}

DWORD WINAPI Func(LPVOID){
.......

}
```

Comment: Передавайте указатель на a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, [один из параметров](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx). Передавайте указатель, а не значение:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

DWORD WINAPI Func(LPVOID param);

int main()
{
    int * param = new int(10);

    CreateThread( 
            NULL,       // default security attributes
            0,          // use default stack size  
            Func,       // thread function name
            param,      // argument to thread function 
            0,          // use default creation flags 
            NULL);

    ... 
}

DWORD WINAPI Func(LPVOID param)
{
    int * number = static_cast<int*>(param);
    std::cout << *number << std::endl;

    delete number;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: понял, спасибо. Нужно подучить указатели и ссылки. Просто с другого языка вернулся в с++.

Comment: @HiHello https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169728/Тип-lpvoid-и-как-им-пользоваться-С

Comment: Еще раз спасибо.